# Connecting to MYSQL with PHP failing (+Swift)

Tags: php, mysql, swift

I am trying to connect to mysql database but for some reason, it cannot establish connection. What I am trying to accomplish is using Swift to send/receive data from an app and register user. [This is the tutorial](http://swiftdeveloperblog.com/store-user-information-in-mysql-database) that I went through. The error I am getting (when I go to domain.com/script.php) is:

> exception 'Exception' with message 'Could not establish connection with
>       database' in /root/blinddate/MySQLDao.php:21 Stack trace: #0 
>       /root/blinddate/script.php(15): MySQLDao->openConnection() #1 {main}

(script.php requires `Connection.php` & `MySQLDao.php` files.

I am suspicious that, it is the inputs I use in Connection.php, however everything seems fine to me.

#### Connection.php

```
<?php

class Conn {
   public static $dbhost = "vps123123.ovh.net";
   public static $dbuser = "root";
   public static $dbpass = "dbpassword";
   public static $dbname = "Test";
  }
?>
```

> $dbhost = I used `mysql > SHOW VARIABLES WHERE Variable_name = 'hostname';` and it gave me `vps123123.ovh.net` so I used that one.
>
> $dbuser = I used `mysql > status` and get `Current user: root@localhost`. So, I used `root`.
>
> $dbpass = The one I use when logging in mysql.
>
> $dbname = Database name that I want to use. I can see it when I use `mysql > SHOW DATABASES`;

#### MySQLDao.php

```
<?php
 class MySQLDao {
   var $dbhost = null;
   var $dbuser = null;
   var $dbpass = null;
   var $conn = null;
   var $dbname = null;
   var $result = null;

   function __construct() {
   $this->dbhost = Conn::$dbhost;
   $this->dbuser = Conn::$dbuser;
   $this->dbpass = Conn::$dbpass;
   $this->dbname = Conn::$dbname;
 }

public function openConnection() {
   $this->conn = new mysqli($this->dbhost, $this->dbuser, $this->dbpass, $this->dbname);
   if (mysqli_connect_errno())
   echo new Exception("Could not establish connection with database");
 }

 //continues
}
?>
```

#### script.php

```
<?php
   require("Conn.php");
   require("MySQLDao.php");
```

Comment: Can u enter that info on a client like workbench or sqlyog and get into the remote server?

Comment: @AsConfused _`Failed to Connect to MySQL at vps123123.ovh.net:3306 with user root. Can't connect to MySQL server on 'vps123123.ovh.net (61)` _

Answer (score 0):

I believe it is one of the following

1) as you haven't shown how you are using the class other than the constructor, that your instance of the class is in who knows state.

2) the outside world cannot resolve to that hostname. Running something on the server doesn't represent how a remote client would

3) the actual error message would help as opposed to your err msg overwrite.

4) my.conf needs tweaked with `bind-address` set to 0.0.0.0 as opposed to localhost or 127.0.0.1

Above #4 requires mysql daemon `restart`

5) grants for user to the dbname

6) google mysql skip-networking

7) firewall

8) `netstat -tulpen`
Search for mysql and see if she is listening on port 3306

Comment: For some reason, I cannot connect on Workbench with same details. Do you have any clue how I can resolve this issue?

Comment: #8 - it is listening :3306

Comment: How from your client box might u communicate to this server were it to have, say apache, running? Hard ipaddress? This is #2

Comment: What is the flavor of this server? On premise? Cloud? MAMP?

Comment: Yes, apache is running (when I go to http://domain.com, Apache window comes and says it works). I didn't get your second question but I am using it through `ssh root@domain.com`. It's not MAMP

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes root user is not allowed to connect with hosts other than 'localhost' . To allow remote connections try and use below

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'%' 
IDENTIFIED BY 'YOUR_PASS' 
WITH GRANT OPTION;
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

This will enable root for other hosts.

Also make sure you are using right hostname. You can get list of incoming requests by using this command.

```
select host from information_schema.processlist;
```

Comment: When I use `select host from information_schema.processlist;` it says: `host > localhost` (even after I use `grant all privileges~`)

Comment: so problem is hostname . If code is residing on same server as mysql , why cant you use localhost OR is MySql instance from different server?

Answer (score 0):

My problem was file permissions. I was getting

```
GET domain.com/script.php 500 (Internal Server Error)
```

I inserted display errors to see the exact error:

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```